# Why is oil filling up in my air intake system?

Tags: chevrolet, repair, oil-leak, cavalier

The car that I am working on displayed below is a 2002 Chevrolet Cavalier 2.2 DOHC. I would like to admit that my knowledge of cars is little to none. I decided to start tinkering around with it because for whatever reason the car would not start one day. I replaced the battery but while doing so I needed to remove `the part labeled '2'` in order to get a socket wrench to remove the bolts going into the battery.

When I removed `2` black engine oil started pouring out of the part labeled `1`. I know that 2 goes to the air filter but I have no clue why `1` and `2` are filling with oil nor do I know what they are called.

Please help me identify the 2 parts and additionally why they are filling with oil if possible?

*I have added the image below*

[image: I have added the image below]

Comment: Was the insides of part #2 covered in oil? Or even a bit greasy?

Comment: well...not covered but it was definitely leaking into it from part 1. Do you have any idea what these parts are?

Comment: Similar problem....https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZMF_OWD72E

Comment: Not much you do about it, the piston rings are getting weak.

Comment: How many miles are on your vehicle?

Comment: What do you mean by bad orifices? Are you referring to a breach in the pcv path inside the valve cover/head, sucking oil into the manifold, or something different?

Comment: @rickford66 I ended up selling the car about a year ago to a junkyard because I can never figure out what was wrong with it. Thanks everyone for your help and Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number 1 looks like your intake manifold and number 2 is your intake hose leading to the throttle body.

If 2-3 ounces of oil come out of #1 when #2 is removed, that's ok. It's most likely oil that's been pushed up by the PCV (Positive Crankcase Ventilation) hose. (Your motor doesn't have a PCV valve, just the hose with a filter on it. Ahhh, Chevy...). If it's more than 2-3 ounces (1-2 shot glasses) then you most likely have either a failed PCV hose or a vacuum leak that causes oil to be sucked into the intake. It might also come from some combination of too much oil, extended high RPMs or aggressive cornering pushing oil into the intake.

My advice is to drain the oil out, measure the amount. If it's not too much, try to keep your oil level below full (about 2/3 to 3/4 is best) and check it again in a week. If it's full again you need that looked at, it will eat O2 sensors and clog your catalytic converters if you don't take care of it. If it's just a little bit, don't worry about it, that's kind of natural with the Chevy "Bent Hose" solution.

Comment: I will try this tonight

Comment: Hey, but now there's no PCV value to get clogged right?  What could go wrong?  Oh... wait.

Comment: the tube going to `1` is the PCV right?

Comment: You are a bit off in what you're naming schema. 1 is an air box. 2 is the air intake ducting. The TB is between the air box and the engine. You can see the TB in [this picture](http://i931.photobucket.com/albums/ad154/cre_oli/2009-11-04155504.jpg). The intake manifold would be between the TB and the engine. It doesn't look like there is much too it.

Comment: That's not the same intake system at all. It's turbocharged and the OP's original picture is not turbo charged. I stand by my nomenclature, the intake manifold IS between the TB and engine. http://screencast.com/t/aEs6Fqgi @Skullomania, check PCV Hose #1 going into the intake and see if it's crusted with old oil or has a lot of oil dripping out. There may also be more hoses like it into the intake manifold.

Answer (score 1):

Oil in your duct, could be a sign that piston rings are weak. Crank could shoot oil up, but if it's a lot you may be sucking oil back up intake valve when it's open because your piston rings are allowing oil into your chamber.

Get a compression test done, 50 bucks at the Chevy dealership. If one of your rings are weak surely your compression will be low. They'll also be able to identify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

These specific engine have orifices running through the intake and if you have a bad (could be original intake) intake you could be putting oil in every two fill ups until you replace the intake.